# Maximum of Stream with custom Comparator

Tags: java, max, java-8, comparator, java-stream

Below is my code written specifically to use custom `Comparator` with `max` in Java 8 `Stream`.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.*;

public class BigDecimalMax  {

    public static BigDecimal getBigDecimalMax(List<forTest> list) {

        return list.stream()
            .filter(t -> t.id % 2 == 0)
            .max(forTestComparator::compare)  //<-- syntax error ----------
            .orElse(null);
    }

    public static class forTestComparator implements Comparator<forTest> {

        @Override
        public int compare(forTest val1, forTest val2) {
            return val1.value.compareTo(val2.value);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<forTest> lst = new ArrayList<>();
        Random rn = new Random();
        BigDecimalMax bdm = new BigDecimalMax();

        for (int i=1; i<22; ++i) {
            lst.add(bdm.new forTest(i, BigDecimal.valueOf(rn.nextLong())));
        }

        System.out.println(getBigDecimalMax(lst));

    }

    class forTest {
        public int id;
        public BigDecimal value;

        forTest(int id, BigDecimal value) {
            this.id = id;
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "forTest{" +
                    "id=" + id +
                    ", value=" + value +
                    '}';
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting a syntax error on a method reference which I don't understand.

```
Error:(15, 18) java: incompatible types: invalid method reference
    cannot find symbol
      symbol:   method compare(BigDecimalMax.forTest, BigDecimalMax.forTest)
      location: class BigDecimalMax.forTestComparator
```

while IntelliJ IDEA complains that `Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context`.

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

---

**ADDITIONAL EXPLANATION** (04/24/14):

1. I understand now the reason for the syntax error. Thank you.
2. **Was custom `Comparator` actually needed here?**

Since `BigDecimal` implements `Comparable` but does **not** seem to implement `Comparator` ( it has `CompareTo()` but **no** `Compare()`) I thought that custom `Comparator` was necessary.  That's why I could not just use `Comparator.comparing(ft -> ft.value)`. Is there a flaw in my logic?

Comment: A custom Comparator isn't needed here. First, this is a confusing area of the API since the names are all so similar. Starting off, you're correct that BigDecimal implements Comparable, but Stream.max() wants a Comparator. The one-arg overload of Comparator.comparing() does this. Also, the ForTest class (original version) doesn't implement either. So you need to supply a lambda `ft -> ft.value` to extract a BigDecimal (which is Comparable) from the ForTest, and then pass this lambda to the one-arg Comparator.comparing() to create a Comparator given the Comparable instances.

Comment: @StuartMarks - I actually read [`comparing` description](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) several times, but only after reading your answer (several times as well) I realized what it meant. So, `comparaing` serves as a *bridge* between `Comparator` and `Comparable`, right?

Comment: Yes that's a good way to describe it. Unfortunately the documentation and the generics in the signature are quite complicated so it's very difficult to learn the usage by just reading the docs. Then you see an example and go "aha!" I hope.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Sotirios Delimanolis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23259339/1441122) shows how to fix the problems, but I have a few things to add.

If you already have a class that implements Comparator, you don't need to use a method reference to its compare() method. You can just pass an instance of it directly, since max() takes a reference to a Comparator:

```
    .max(new forTestComparator())
```

or

```
    forTestComparator instance = new forTestComparator();
    ...
    .max(instance)
```

However, the combinator functions on Comparator usually make it unnecessary to have a class that implements Comparator. For example, you can get rid of the `forTestComparator` class entirely and just do this:

```
    .max(Comparator.comparing(ft -> ft.value))
```

or if `forTest` were to have the obvious getValue() method, one could rewrite the stream max() call as follows:

```
    .max(Comparator.comparing(forTest::getValue))
```

In addition, if you wanted to make `forTest` implement the `Comparable` interface, you could do this:

```
public class forTest implements Comparable<forTest> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(forTest other) {
        return this.value.compareTo(other.value);
    }
    ...
}
```

and the way to use max() on a Comparable is:

```
    .max(Comparator.naturalOrder())
```

---

Two style notes:

1. I strongly discourage using `orElse(null)` on instances of `Optional`. This is allowed, though probably its main purpose to retrofit use of new Java 8 APIs into code that's expecting null to indicate the absence of a value. Avoid `orElse(null)` if you possibly can, since this forces the caller to check for null. Instead, substitute an actual value to replace an absent value, or return the `Optional` itself to the caller, so the caller can apply whatever policy it wants.
2. I recommend sticking to the established Java naming conventions of capitalized, mixed-case class names. The class names `forTest` and `forTestComparator` make this code kind of difficult to work with, since they don't *look* like class names.

Comment: Thank you. I addressed one of your suggestions by adding my reasoning to the original post. Could you please have a look?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Comparator.naturalOrder(). I've long been annoyed that I have to provide a Comparator for classes that already Comparable.

Answer (score 6):

`forTestComparator#compare` is an instance method. You need an **instance** method reference, as opposed to a `static` method reference that you have.

Something like

```
new forTestComparator()::compare
```

or the long way (your class doesn't have instance state, so you don't really care about the reference)

```
forTestComparator instance = new forTestComparator(); // fix for Java conventions
return list.stream()
        .filter(t -> t.id % 2 == 0)
        .max(instance::compare)  //<-- syntax error ----------
        .orElse(null);
```

See the Java tutorial on method references [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

> Reference to an instance method of a particular object `-> ContainingObject::instanceMethodName`

---

Side note, this

```
return list.stream()
            .filter(t -> t.id % 2 == 0)
            .max(new forTestComparator()::compare)  
            .orElse(null);
```

resolves in a `forTest` value. You need to change the return type of your method.

Comment: +1 for fixing the problems, and see my answer for additional points.

Comment: Special thanks for the side note. I have not realized its importance at first.